# How to view an image stored in Google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket that has images stored in it , when I retrieve the image using the public URL of the image it downloads it in the browser instead of showing the image in the browser , how can I view the image instead of downloading it. I use the following URL for the uploaded image.

https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/image-downloader-bucket/o/a06266f6-6082-468e-92ca-f918a48533a8?generation=1455661996337000&alt=media

Can someone let me know how to create the right URL for viewing the image ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the object is publicly readable, you can view it directly at "https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME", which in your case would be https://storage.googleapis.com/image-downloader-bucket/a06266f6-6082-468e-92ca-f918a48533a8.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what was needed!

Comment: is there a way to resize the image , or request the image with some specific dimensions ?

Comment: this is what I needed

Comment: "publicly readable" does this mean people can see all bucket's contents if they open https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/???

Comment: That's the case if the public is publicly readable. The object can have permissions that the bucket lacks (unless uniform bucket level access is enabled).

Answer (score 12):

My problem was that I wasn't setting the mimetype for the object. Without it, the browser didn't know it was an image, so it was downloading the file instead of displaying it in the browser window

Adding this did the trick:

```
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
  metadata: {
    contentType: "image/jpeg"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the @ehero response but for python, the point is using content_type blob attribute before uploading the file:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('your/path/to/service/credentials.json')
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my-bucket-name')
blob = bucket.blob('my/path/in/storage.jpg')
blob.content_type = 'image/jpeg' # This one is the important
blob.upload_from_file(file) # Also available upload_from_filename
```

Comment: did you get ti from documentation?, if not can i ask you a general question, how someone should know about these things general when programming, I've struggled a bit without a clue until got here ..?

Comment: you're right, you need to set the content-type in the object. In java a did it in Blob info

`BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucket, key)).setContentType("image/jpeg").build()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! You actually resize the image of your file stored in Google Cloud Storage thru the Images API. Have a look at this link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Google cloud console-> Storage->Browser
  https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser
- Click on your bucket
- You can select an image/file in bucket and edit access by clicking on the 3 dots option and make it public.
- It will generate public URL

See for details: [make data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)